# I don't want to use Xpath to map the Label element

Tags: automated-tests, capybara, site-prism

I don't want to use xpath to map these elements, as we can see the class is the same for everyone. How to do please?

```html
<label class="sc-fzowVh juqfMo">CNPJ:*</label>
<label class="sc-fzowVh juqfMo">CPF: (do usuário)*</label>
```

xpath:

```
//*[@id="boxCadastro"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/label
//*[@id="boxCadastro"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/label
```

See the image please: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzTnT.png)

Comment: An id should be unique per document. So, this is bad markup. But Capybara can find things by class or id; it just won't work well in your case because of the mistaken use of the ID element.

Comment: Exactly why I am looking for help !! .. Can you help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML surrounding each of those label elements in order to be able to use scoping, the only option is to go with text matching on the label contents

```
element :label1, :css, 'label', text: 'CNPJ:*'
element :label2, :css, 'label', text: 'CPF: (do usuário)*'
```

or using the :label selector type

```
element :label1, :label, 'CNPJ:*'
element :label2, :label, 'CPF: (do usuário)*'
```

although having `label` elements without `for` attributes is generally a bad practice and negatively affects page accessibility, so you may want to talk to your developers about improving their HTML

Comment: Your are The Best!!!!.. Thank  you, Thank'u  X 1000